# Scan table in stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I want to put in an array some columns of a table in sql server.

for example

```
att1 att2 att3  att4 att5
-------------------------
1   2   3   4   5
5   6   7   8   9   
10  11  12  13  14
```

I want to have it into an array only the first 3 columns

like

`[1,2,3,5,6,7,10,11,12]`

so i am skipping columns att4 and att5

Comment: not what a relational database is good at, or should be used for....

Comment: yeah, I am just comparing some things

Comment: your comment makes little sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dataList = new List<object>();

while (reader.Read()) 
{
    var values = new object[reader.FieldCount];
    var fieldCount = reader.GetValues(values);

    dataList.AddRange(values);
}

//var arrayData = dataList.ToArray()
var arrayData = dataList.ConvertAll<double>(o => (double) o).ToArray();
```

Comment: Is there a way to get arrayData as an array of doubles, because that is array of objects...

Comment: Updated. Make sure that all columns can be converted to double.